# Are there any magazines similar to InQuest Gamer in print today?

Tags: recommendations

When I was young, I begged my parents for a subscription to InQuest Gamer (a magazine mostly about collectable card games). I remember reading the articles and learning about new games every month. At the time I played mostly Magic The Gathering, but I was interested in learning/playing other games. The magazine was discontinued.

Years later, I still have some back issues (my favorite being the one that came with the board game Space Station Zemo - That's right; the magazine came with a board game in it). I was wondering if there are any similar publications. I play all kinds of games (table top RPGs, card games, but mostly board games). I would like to read quality articles talking about games of the past or new games intermixed with other that games would like (InQuest had articles about the history of games, mythology, short stories, house rules, etc.). It doesn't have to be print; I read digital magazines.

So, does a magazine similar to InQuest exist today?

Comment: I still wonder WHY inquest gamer was discontinued.

Comment: I wonder if there are any websites that replicate the sort of articles and entertainment value the magazines used to provide?  Or do you have a specific reason for wanting a print magazine?

Comment: @DForck42 As a former editor of **InQuest Gamer**, I can answer that question: the rise of the Internet as a medium for CCG and game-related information, the crash in comic-book value and the subsequent negative effect on InQuest's parent (Wizard Entertainment), and the overall adoption of the "InQuest Style" by its competition. If DailyMTG.com is making funny cartoons with Magic cards, then the need for a magazine like InQuest is somewhat diminished, right?

Comment: @thesunneversets The OP seems to be okay with online publications, as per the last line of the second paragraph.

Comment: I'd be fine with a website for this type of content. Ars technica sometimes reviews board games (see http://arstechnica.com/gaming/reviews/2011/07/chaostle-turns-dungeon-crawling-into-a-bloody-competitive-brawl.ars).  @Jadasc You guys did an awesome job with InQuest.

Comment: @Dave Thank you; you're kind to say so. I'm still really proud of some of the work I did back then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking around, I found a couple online magazines

http://www.meoplesmagazine.com/

http://www.flagshipmagazine.co.uk/index.php?a=home

I also found a list of magazines on the geek:

http://boardgamegeek.com/wiki/page/Game_Magazines

Not exactly what I was looking for, but it's better than nothing.